# ImageBaseAddress of PEB

Tags: portable-executable

When I dump the data at the ImageBaseAddress from the PEB output for some programs, I could the see the MS-DOS header. But it is not appearing for some other programs. What is the reason?

For example, when I dump the PEB of SVCHost.exe this is the output
[image]

When I try to dump the ImageBaseAddress of the notepad.exe, this is the output.
[image]

Comment: Are you in the context of the right process when you do this? In other words, are tou attached to notepad.exe? What happens if you do a `.reload` first?

Comment: Thanks for the input. After switching to the notepad process context, i see the proper data.